# HTTP Post with header and parameters ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, http-post

I'd like to send POST request to an API which is described in documentation, but only with PHP examples.

Here is screen which shows what should be send to API
[image]

For now my code looks like this:

```
        string URI = "https://api.monetivo.com/v1/auth/login";
        string myParameters = "login=2DY9&password=346f417edb495e484b67";

        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            wc.Headers.Add("X-API-Token", "test_d7b8ddfe-fae6-404c-84fe-02c6d5d292e4");
            string HtmlResult = wc.UploadString(URI, myParameters);
        }
```

I always get error 401 `No authorization`. I need help with that how should I code it to send request with parameters and specific header.

Comment: That is how you add a header. You will have to talk to the owners of the API.

Comment: @GabrielLuci So everything is written fine yes?

Comment: "Fine" depends on what the API expects. All I can say is that you properly added the "X-API-Token" header with a value of "test_d7b8ddfe-fae6-404c-84fe-02c6d5d292e4".

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the data structure I think you have to specify `x-www-form-urlencoded` as content type.

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    wc.Headers["X-API-Token"] = "test_d7b8ddfe-fae6-404c-84fe-02c6d5d292e4";
    string HtmlResult = wc.UploadString(URI, myParameters);
}
```

But apart from it I would suggest you to consider passing the data as [**NameValueCollection (see msdn)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w7b4fz7(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
var param = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
param.Add("login", "2DY9");
param.Add("password", "346f417edb495e484b67");
```